# Default Accessibility Label for UIViewController's View

Tags: ios, label, accessibility, uiaccessibility

Apple's UIAccesibility Protocol [reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615181-accessibilitylabel) states:

> UIAccessibilityLabel
>
> ### Discussion
>
> The default value for this property is nil unless the receiver is a UIKit control, in which case the value is a label derived from the control’s title.

Well... both UIView and UIViewController are in the UIKit framework, but I can't find the default accessibility label for my view who's controlled by the UIViewController named LoginVC. I tried to log it, but get a blank string. Is that right? is the doc wrong? Or am I doing something wrong?

I know I can set the accessibility label manually; I'd like to avoid the clutter and use defaults if possible - which are already generally descriptive if their name is actually derived from their controller.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a `UIView` and a `UIViewController` have nothing set for their `title` property, so the default `accessibilityLabel` property (which is derived from the `title` property) correctly and expectedly returns `nil`. Set their `title` properties (either in code or in Interface Builder) and you'll see it when you log `accessibilityLabel` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Accessibility will populate itself automatically, if that's what you're asking.

If you asking for ways to set it, you should be able to do it programmatically:

```
[myButton setAccessibilityLabel:@"Hello"];
```

If you use Interface Builder, there is a field in the Identity Inspector tab that will allow you to set this. Select your view under Objects on the left. Then click the third tab from the left for Identity Inspector. Example below:

[image]